# Pinterest shows conversion tag working and show events counts for Add to cart, checkout, but it is not reflecting in Google analytics referral report

Tags: google-analytics, tags, pinterest

I am working on pinterest conversion tag set up via GTM, I successfully installed both base code and event code in GTM,
[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OjSO.png)

And later i started pinterest ads. I saw lots of pinterest vists are coming to my ads and pinterest is reporting conversion event (add to cart) counts to 1,.. [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLe0D.png) but when i go into google analytics referral report then it shows nothing. I want to make sure about its implementation of event tracking. Did it has wrong implementation ? please help me on correct way of installation and verification of pinterest conversion tag.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you are looking in the "referral report" for traffic coming from Pinterest Ads. Didn't you set UTM parameters to your destination URLs of your campaigns ?

Comment: thank you for replying, No i did not set UTM parameters. Will this work and how can I set? Also how do i check conversion under goal in Google analytics I have created Add to cart and Checkout goals.

Comment: Every conversion analysis per marketing channel in GA relies on the proper use of UTM parameters. Do you set UTM for other channels ? I couldn't find a good article on how to set UTM for Pinterest...